# Qt6Widgets.dll cannot load error "Squish 7.0.0 Qt 6.2.3"

Tags: qt, squish

I am using Squish 7.0.0 6.2x for my Qt application which is built on Qt 6.2.3. While launching the AUT from squish its throw error "could not load Qtwidgets library qt6widgests.dll : The specified module could not be found."

While launching AUT standalone mode, its works fine. The application package doesn't have this dll. Need help for below. I tried to search the dll for download but it's not available.

1. How to avoid this error in Squish tool (such as disabling/enabling configuration).
2. How to build this dll along with my AUT.

Answer (score 0):

Squish for Qt binary packages have a dependency on that shared library.

If the Qt build, that the application gets build with, has Qt Widgets enabled (the default for the binaries provided by The Qt Company), it has this shared library in its folder ("bin" on Windows, "lib" on Unix and others):

- Making the DLL available via PATH (LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Unix, DY_LD_LIBRARY_PATH on macOS) is sufficient.
- Copying the file into the folder with the Qt DLLs used by your application is sufficient, too.

To remove the dependency, please contact the vendor and report the issue to them, so that they can provide the sources of Squish, for following the [Quick Install](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ins-commandline-tools-server-ide.html#ins-quick) approach to update an existing Squish for Qt binary package to make it compatible with that Qt build (that possibly lacks the Qt Widget module).